# How to use hook_menu_link_alter() on taxonomy term view?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes

When viewing a taxonomy term, I want to change the 'Edit' link (in the admin tabs) to say 'Edit this term' instead.

In taxonomy.module, the menu item is defined like this:

```
function taxonomy_menu() {
    $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit'] = array(
        'title' => 'Edit',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        // Pass a NULL argument to ensure that additional path components are not
        // passed to taxonomy_form_term() as the vocabulary machine name argument.
        'page arguments' => array('taxonomy_form_term', 2, NULL),
        'access callback' => 'taxonomy_term_edit_access',
        'access arguments' => array(2),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'weight' => 10,
        'file' => 'taxonomy.admin.inc',
      );
}
```

So in my module, I try to do this:

```
function mymodule_menu_link_alter(&$item, $menu) {
  if ($item['link_path'] == 'taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit') {
    $item['link_title'] = 'Edit this term';
  };
}
```

After clearing cache and rebuilding menus, the menu item still says 'Edit'.

Is this because the menu item type is MENU_LOCAL_TASK? Or perhaps I am missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just implementing the wrong hook...you need [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) instead

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit']['title'] = 'Edit this term';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[hook_menu_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7) is invoked from [menu_link_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7), which is the function called when a menu link is saved. The code you wrote for that hook would be invoked when, for example, you add a menu link from admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/add, and use taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit as value for *Path*.

As Clive said, `hook_menu_alter()` is the hook you should use to change the menu item defined in `hook_menu()` from a module.