# Create hierarchical taxonomy url alias with token term:parents using a field other than term:name

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, tokens, path-aliases

Sorry, the title is a bit of a mouthful but I will attempt to clarify.

I have a question about pathauto tokens to create a URL alias for a nested/hierarchical taxonomy.

Specifically, I have a taxonomy called Category, which is `n` layers deep; e.g:

> Category level 01 > Category level 02 > Category level 03

And so on. The question appears to have been asked many times before and there are a number of good solutions, [including the following pattern](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/75953/23717):

> [term:parents:join:/]/[term:name]

This yields the following url alias for the above example:

> category-level-01/category-level-02/category-level-03

Pretty straightforward. This would be perfect except in my example the taxonomy terms are in Chinese.

I need English in the path aliases, so I have set up a new field in my taxonomy called 'Name English'. This gives me the following replacement pattern:

> [term:parents:join:/]/[term:field_name_english]

Which is almost perfect, but the parents default to using the `name` field, and there does not seem to be an easy way of overriding this. I cannot use the parent taxonomy terms with delta because it's not dynamic; e.g:

> [term:parents-all:1:field_name_english]/[term:field_name_english]

Some taxonomy depths will be deeper than others.

---

So, in summary, I need to somehow specify an alternate term field to name for the `[term:parents]` token. To do this I assume I will need to do one of the following:

1. Create a custom token
2. Override the current `[term:parents]` token

Can anyone advise on this? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

You could copy the token created by the taxonomy module for [term:parents:join:/] and recreate it in your own module, using your field as a substitute for title.

This would require some familiarity with the token system. There is also a module entitled '[Custom Token](https://drupal.org/project/token_custom)' that might be worth a look, though I have not used it.

### Option 2

One divergent way I could suggest to get around this is to use drupal's title field to store your english language title, and another field to store the chinese title (*field_chinese_title*).

You could then preprocess the node title within your theme/module to replace $variables['title'] with *field_chinese_title*. You might also have to do this for menu entries and search results, and you would also have to remember to use *field_chinese_title* for views fields etc.

*YOURTHEME/template.php:*

```
<?php
function YOURTHEME_process_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']->field_chinese_title['und'][0]['value'])) {
    $variables['title'] = $variables['node']->field_chinese_title['und'][0]['value'];
  }
}

function YOURTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  // use chinese version of title for search results
  if (isset($variables['result']['node']->field_chinese_title)) {
    $variables['title'] = $variables['result']['node']->field_chinese_title['und'][0]['value']);
  }
}
```

I admit I have little experience of multi language sites, and I do realise that this method might look a little crude, but I have used a variation (with autonodetitle) to differentiate the titles used by menu entries and nodes (so that menu entries can optionally be more concise) and it works beautifully. For my use case, I later found a module for that...

Comment: Hi there. That's great, thanks for the feedback. I was originally thinking along the lines of option #1 - I am not very familiar with Drupal's internals, but I am proficient enough with PHP to do some overriding, if I can find the code in question. The only problem is that I haven't been able to pinpoint the `[term:parents:join:/]` code yet.

Comment: Option #2 is definitely food for thought - I'm just reading/digesting it now to see if I understand it properly :)

Comment: Actually, yes, I am populating the menu with taxonomy terms, using the Taxonomy Menu module. I guess, as you noted, I will have to override the menu hook as well then? A quick google would seem to suggest `hook_menu_alter`: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51255/23717

Comment: Thanks a million for the information - I ended up reneging on the nested taxonomy url alias in the end but this will prove useful in future and it was an all-round informative answer so cheers!

Comment: no problem, glad to be of some help