# Pathauto and Token to get the first child term

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I am trying to create URL path aliases patterns with Tokens and Pathauto.

My main issue is how to I get the child of a parent of a taxonomy term? So my url is something like this.

[child-term:name]/[node:name]

In tokens help page I can see a lot [term:parent] references but not child ones. I am sure is something simple but in the vast amount of tokens I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create hierarchical taxonomy url alias with token term:parents using a field other than term:name](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96561/create-hierarchical-taxonomy-url-alias-with-token-termparents-using-a-field-oth)

Comment: Thanks @zhilevan for the indication...I don't think is a duplicate though because is quite a different question. I have one more question though. The pattern I used is [node:field-region-city-location:1:name]/[node:title]. I don't get the delta value I used and why it works that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @zhilevan and the link provided in his comment I got some hints.

In any case what actually worked is this:

[node:field-region-city-location:1:name]/[node:title]

So now I get correctly [child-term:name]/[node:name]

Thanks for the guidance everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can do quite advanced things with [`hook_pathauto_alias_alter`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto_alias_alter/7) to replace complex aliases patterns with just PHP code.

Here's how to use it:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_alias_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
  // Make sure we're dealing with nodes
  if (isset($context['module']) && $context['module'] == 'node') {
    // If this is a "my_content_type" content type
    if ($context['type'] == 'my_content_type') {
      $node = $context['data']['node'];

      // do stuff with $node, such as getting the taxonomy term
      // and loading the term.. then getting the children terms etc..

      // then assign a string value to $alias 
      $alias = pathauto_cleanstring($child_term->name) . '/' . pathauto_cleanstring($node->title); // for example...

      // Clean the alias
      $function = 'pathauto_clean_alias';
      if (function_exists($function)) {
        $alias = $function($alias);
      }

      // Now just make sure the alias generated is unique to this node.
      $function = 'pathauto_alias_uniquify';
      if (function_exists($function)) {
        $source = 'node/'.$node->nid;
        $lang = $node->language;

        $function($alias, $source, $lang);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I actually used Tokens with no need of any custom code.